# Why Can't my application open a file that exists?

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm currently building a Web Service that sends files this also obtains the mime-type from the file is sending but for some reason my application can't see the file let alone open.

My path is

```
file:\\C:\\Users\\Martin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\HTML5Streamer\\
Debug\\Player\\player.html
```

(this is created by my application. My application is compiled to the debug folder in that path when I use Chrome locally and paste that address it works fine, chrome can see and access the file,

My VS is running as Administrator so the application compile is also running as Admin why would it get the correct path then the `File.Exists()` says it does not exist

```
 public string getMimeFromFile(string filename)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(filename))
            throw new FileNotFoundException(filename + " not found"); // this is thrown

        byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
        {
            if (fs.Length >= 256)
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
            else
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
        }
        try
        {
            System.UInt32 mimetype;
            FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
            System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
            string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
            return mime;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "unknown/unknown";
        }
    }
```

The method calling this is

```
private void ProccessPlayerRequest(HttpListenerContext context)
        {
            Uri content_uri = context.Request.Url;
            string filePath = ApplicationPath + content_uri.AbsolutePath.Replace('/', '\\');
//ApplicationPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            string mimeType = getMimeFromFile(filePath);

            context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type: " + mimeType);
            streamFileToBrowser(filePath, context);
        }
```

When using `string filePath = Path.Combine(ApplicationPath, @"Player\player.html");` produced

```
"file:\\C:\\Users\\Martin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\HTML5Streamer\\Debug\\Player\\player.html"
```

and yes file:\ is got from the .Net Framework with

```
string ApplicationPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
            Service serv = new Service(ApplicationPath);
```

This application path sent into the constructor is what is given from all the correct calls so please dont say it should not have file:\ as that is given by the .Net Framework

Comment: What does your filePath variable look like after you set it? You should use Path.Combine for one.

Comment: My File path that is generated is in my Question please read before asking

Comment: I read your question. I'm not sure if that's the path you HOPE that it is or that is the acutal path that filePath holds. Skip the attitude when you need help ;)

Comment: if i go to my path in my browser it become a URI of `file:///C://Users//Martin//Documents//Visual%20Studio%202010//Projects//HTML5Streamer//Debug//Player//player.html` 

As for the backslashes in windows ` \ ` is the correct filepath `/` is linux/mac so when shown ` \\ ` is correctly escaped for windows and the path works in Explorer if i remove the escaping form the address E.G change the ` \\ ` to ` \ ` for explorer

Comment: Stakx WTF that was correct it is double backslash don't edit what you don't know!!!

Comment: @banging "this is created by my application"???

Comment: @Martin: Evidently you don't know that the debugger shows double backslashes that aren't there.  And Stakx's edit was correct.

Comment: No the Debugger show the exact string to use if you were to do it as a string E.G `string path = "path\\goes\\here"` as i was showing what is given from the application not what i want it to use,

all using @ does is make the compiler escape it for you E.G lasy coders who want to put more load on the compiler in stead if a little extra work from them, i work in a Software house where the software is 367 project take a good 20 mins to compile on a top of the range system with out debug and we have teams removing @'s to reduce that time and no this is not for work before any one asks

Comment: Thanks for every one not arguing with me now if any one wants to argue with the @ thing please go read the information i have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `file:\\` from the start of the filename.

**Edit:**  Try using `Application.ExecutablePath` instead of the CodeBase reference in your `Path.GetDirectoryName()` call.  You may have to add a reference to the assembly `System.Windows.Forms`.

```
string ApplicationPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

**Edit2:**

You may also be able to use (taken from a dll of mine):

```
public static FileInfo Application()
{
    return new FileInfo(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
}
```

Then:

```
string ApplicationPath = Application().DirectoryName;
```

Comment: ... and make sure to think about escaping the backslashes in string literals: both `"C:\\Ping\\Pong.txt"` and `@"C:\Ping\Pong.txt"` are fine.

Comment: @MartinBarker Added an Edit that may help get the proper directory. (without the `file:\\` ).  Because it is the CodeBase that is giving the `file:\\` and just because it gives it doesn't mean it is right for your case.

Comment: EDIT comment: from VS "The name 'Application' does not exist in the current context" and that was got from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx

Comment: Add the assembly reference, `System.Windows.Forms`.  Even though you are not using win forms, it should still work for you.

Comment: I just tested this myself, using the CodeBase version, a file doesn't exist for me either that I know exists.  But replace it with the `Application.ExecutablePath` and it does.  I do hope this works for you too.

Comment: Yes thanks it has going to write a loverly Email to MS saying that as a Registered MSDN developer there Own documentation stinks and is wrong P.S i did have the manually add the reference to System.Windows.Forms for me to use the using just add that to your answer and i will mark it as correct

Comment: @MartinBarker I added it to the answer, though I used the word `may` as others than you will read the post in the future and use my answer to help themselves.

Answer (score 0):

`System.IO.File` works with file names, not URIs, so the `file:/` prefix won't be recognized. Chrome works because it's converting a URI to a system file name for you.